# Why neutrinos are weakly interacting?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos

I recently attended a talk on neutrinos, where the speaker said there are billions of neutrinos passes through our body every second, but in our lifetime the probability of alteast one neutrino interacting with our body is very low.  It is weakly interacting why? Is there any reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are neutrinos more weakly interacting than light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133866/)

Comment: Hi Muthu, we encourage new users to search the site to check if there question, or one very like it, has been asked before. In this case [the obvious search](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutrino+weakly+is%3Aquestion) quickly finds the duplicate I've suggested.