# Why are neutrinos so hard to detect in comparison to photons?

Tags: neutrinos

Everywhere i look it says neutrinos are hard to detect as they dont interact electromagnetically, however neither do photons and photons have no mass so i dont't understand why we can detect photons so easily in comparison to neutrinos.

Comment: Why do you say photons don't interact electromagnetically?

Comment: Photons are the carriers of E&M interactions.

Comment: You will find the answer here. Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133866/154997

Answer (score 4):

> neither do photons [interact electromagnetically]

It's true that photons don't interact (directly) with photons since photons are not electrically charged.  But the electromagnetic interaction of *electrically charged* particles is via photons, i.e., two electrons interact (electromagnetically) via photons.  We way that photons mediate the electromagnetic interaction.

Neutrinos, on the other hand, are *not* electrically charged and thus (in the Standard Model) do not interact or participate in electromagnetic interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Neutrinos don't interact with matter very well and the reason for that is because they have no electrical charge and very very little mass. The only way a neutrino can interact with us is through the weak nuclear force since the gravitational interaction is virtually useless and they have no way to interact electromagnetically.